# unable to create new static Library out of existing source code

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, static-libraries

I'v done quite a bit of R&D on creating static libraries in iOS and came across some well written blogs. I followed [this link](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html) and also [this](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/04/universal-static-libraries/) to create a static library. I have follwed the steps specified in those blogs i.e, i added all the implementation files(.m) to the static library and deleted them from the main target etc... But, i am getting around 700 erros (which is quite bizarre) when i try to build the code. i am posting a screenshot of my errors here..
Is there anything that i am missing here or doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check the imported Header files.

The .m files, which have these errors, may have the same imported files.

Maybe a semi-comma or parentheses is missing or used incorrectly.

Comment: all these .m files have some imported classes. What should i do with them?